# ZF: using controller forward() method makes init() method fire twice

Tags: zend-framework

Is it bug or is it by design? If second, it seems illogical... Why to re-initialise if it is already initialised? Or am I wrong?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$this->_forward()` methods works like an internal (3xx) redirect. It's meant to set a new environment like a new request. This will be especially helpful and obvious when you work with modules.

For forwarding to another action inside the same controller you should use `$this->dispatch('nextAction')`.

Comment: Didn't know about dispath(), I was sure it is what the forward() method is intended for.
Sometimes there is no time to investigate the sources...
Thank you!